# Why is the constant pool (in Java classfile) indexed from 1 (and not 0)? What is the constant_pool[0] entry reserved for?

Tags: java, jvm, .class-file

From the JVM specs ([Chapter 4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html) "The ClassFile structure"), it is stated that "The constant_pool table is indexed from 1 to constant_pool_count - 1."

I'm curious why they're skipping [0] and what is this entry reserved for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They skipped index 0 so that it can be used for cases where you would normally reference a constant pool entry, but instead want to indicate "nothing". It is the constant pool equivalent of a null pointer.

The most notable use for index 0 is for "catch all" exception handlers. An exception handler can either point to the constant pool entry for the class of exceptions it wants to handle, or just use index 0 to catch everything (this is equivalent to catching `java/lang/Throwable`). In practice, the compiler will generate catch all exception handlers to implement `finally`, `synchronized` blocks, and the cleanup portions of try with resources, among other things.

Other uses for index 0 include:

- The superclass of `java/lang/Object`
- The name of a parameter with no name
- The outer class for classes which are not the member of another class (i.e. top level classes, local classes, and anonymous classes)
- The inner name of anonymous classes
- The enclosing method for classes which are not immediately enclosed in a method
- Version info for a module with no version info
- Dependencies for a module with no dependency info

Comment: Thank you for this very clear and informative answer!

Comment: Interestingly, only the first point existed in Java 1.0 when the decision was made. So the first constant pool index was reserved for a single corner case…

Comment: @Holger Did Java 1.0 have synchronized blocks? Because those are implemented with catch [0] as well.

Comment: Well, yes, `synchronized` and `finally`. But, as you said, this “catch all” idiom is equivalent to catching `java/lang/Throwable` and doesn’t really need a special encoding. Nowadays, it doesn’t even save a single byte, as an exception handler always requires a stackmap declaring the stack item, in case of “catch all” it’s of type `java/lang/Throwable`, so the exception handler could refer to the same pool entry instead of zero. Further, using `0xFFFF` instead of zero for that purpose allowed `LDC` to address one more pool entry, but well, the decision was made a quarter century ago…

Answer (score 1):

There is no reserved entry.  "[I]ndexed from 1" means that the first entry in the constant pool corresponds to index 1, so there isn't any constant_pool[0].  Rather, there is a reserved *index*, 0, that is known with certainty to not be a valid index into the constant pool.

Documented uses for that reserved index seem to be rare, but at least section 4.7.24 specifies a use: method parameters' names are represented by indexes into the constant pool, and for unnamed parameters, that index is given as 0.

Note also that the name `constant_pool_count` is misleading.  The specification explicitly says that there are only `constant_pool_count - 1` entries in the constant pool (see the structure declaration at the top of section 4.1, and compare to some of the other members).

Comment: There are several other cases where index 0 is used. The most notable is for "catch all" exception handlers.